# Is it possible to "constify" a field of `std::pair` without hacks?

Tags: c++, casting, constants, std-pair

In C++, the compiling the following code:

```
std::pair <int, int>  x;
static_cast <std::pair <const int, int>*> (&x);
```

gives an error:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘std::pair<int, int>*’ to type ‘std::pair<const int, int>*’
```

I more or less understand why it happens, as cv-qualifying a type in a template parameter list can, in principle, give an "incompatible" result.  And even if in this case it doesn't, compiler has no way to know it.

Anyway, *is there a non-hackish way to perform this conversion*?  I'm wary of using `reinterpret_cast` for anything as I've been by type-punning problems before.  Also, I can't use temporaries since this is in performance-critical code.

**EDIT:**

Here is what I'm doing.  I'm implementing a custom container interface-compatible with `std::unordered_map`.  Because of that, its `value_type` needs to be a `pair <const key_type, mapped_type>`.  For some optimization, I need to *internally* store the values as `pair <key_type, mapped_type>`, without `const`.  However, if I do that, I can't (without `reinterpret_cast`) implement iterators over the container, as they need to return references to values and I have only references to these non-const pairs.

Comment: What is your intended use case for this?  I'm having a hard time seeing how this would be used.

Comment: You could keep two such structs and define a conversion function from the less const to the more const one.

Comment: @James McNellis: My guess is that he has one function which returns a pair<int, int> and another which takes a pair<const int, int>*

Comment: @James McNellis: Maps have `pair <const key_type, mapped_type>` as their `value_type`, so I need (or seem to need, maybe there are still alternatives) for some optimization.

Comment: @doublep:  Perhaps if you show the code you are trying to optimize it would help.

Comment: @James McNellis: Done, see the edit in the question text.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a cast, but you can do the following:

```
std::pair<int, int>  x;
std::pair<const int, int> y( x );
```

This should work according to §20.2.2/4.

Comment: The trick is `y.second` needs to refer to the same variable as `x.second`.  Maybe `std::pair<const int, int&> y(x.first, x.second)` might work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
template< typename T1, typename T2 >
struct ref_pair {
public:
    typedef const T1 first_type;
    typedef T2 second_type;

    ref_pair(first_type& f, second_type& s) : f_(f), s_(s) {}

    first_type& first() {return *f_;}
    second_type& second() {return *s_;}
private:
    first_type* f_;
    second_type* s_;
};
```

I know, it's different, those are functions. If you're really desperate, you can turn `first` and `second` into objects of some proxy type which delay-evaluate `*f_` and `*s_`.
However, in the end there's always a way users can tell the difference.

---

I think the following would be reasonably safe and portable, although, of course, with `reinterpret_cast` nothing is guaranteed:

```
std:::pair<const int,int>& rx = reinterpret_cast<std:::pair<const int,int>&>(x);
```

It feels dirty, though. I'm now going to wash my hands.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272141/is-casting-stdpairt1-t2-const-to-stdpairt1-const-t2-const-safe