# C++ const correctness with std::pair

Tags: c++, constants

I am maintaining a container class with an interface similar to `std::map`/`std::unordered_map`.

The interface claims to store `std::pair<const X,Y>` (i.e that's what `value_type` is). Internally, however, the implementation stores a sorted array of `std::pair<X,Y>`.

The current implementation uses `reinterpret_cast` to implement the iterators. My question is, is there a better alternative?

Moving to storing an array of `std::pair<const X,Y>` wouldn't be possible, as the implementation needs to copy elements around in the array to implement insertion and deletion. One of the ways it does this is using `std::sort`.

---

**Edit:** Although I believe the `reinterpret_cast` invokes undefined behavior (or implementation defined?) I have yet to come across a compiler where this doesn't work - Am I worrying about nothing?

---

Current implementation of iterator's dereference:

```
template <class K, class M>
std::pair<const K,M>& operator*() {
  std::pair<K,M>& result = ...;
  return *reinterpret_cast<std::pair<const K,M>*)(&result);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but wouldn't const_cast be preferable to reinterpret_cast?

Comment: @Benj `const_cast` can't do the job here.

Comment: Why can't you have internal consts? Perhaps you can change assignment to destruction/reconstruction?

Comment: your problem with `const X` is that you need to copy elements when inserting or deleting. I'm not sure it's entirely legal, but you might be able to change `pair1 = pair2` to a manual call to the destructor (`pair1.~pair()`), followed by copy construction placement new (`new(&pair1) pair(pair2)`). Codesamples simplyfied for space reasons

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I think that's the only solution that works and is well defined. However, it will significantly complicate the implementation.  I won't be able to call `std::sort` as it will try to copy/move rather than construct/destruct.

Comment: @Grizzly: That's significantly messier than the reinterpret_cast solution, although it might be legal. I'll investigate.

Comment: Mooing Duck's comment under Mark B's answer point to this duplicate [Is it possible to "constify" a field of `std::pair` without hacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638541/is-it-possible-to-constify-a-field-of-stdpair-without-hacks)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can't solve this by returning a `std::pair`. Instead, you're going to have to return a proxy object that *looks* like a standard pair, but if you update the `second` member it propagates through to the main container, while the first member is expose as `const` as you desire.

Comment: Having a similar project to the OP, This doesn't seem like it would be as easy as you make it sound.  Maybe though.  I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638541 gives the idea of returning a `std::pair<const K&, M&>(first, second)`, completely different object, but users shouldn't be able to tell.

Answer (score 1):

"Better alternative?" What is wrong with `reinterpret_cast`? In this case, the cast is even well-defined since you're casting between objects with compatible (in fact, identical) representations.