# Const Conversion in std::pair

Tags: c++, std-pair

How can I convert `std::pair<const string,int>` to `std::pair<string,int>` without actually making a new pair?

I tried using static_cast as below:

```
static_cast<std::pair<const string, int>>(curr->valPair)
```

curr->valPair - is returning `std::pair<string,int>`

But it is returning error:

```
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int>’
```

[Edit: In short the question is how to convert `std::pair<string,int>` to `std::pair<const string,int>`]

Edit2:

Adding a small piece of code to reproduce the issue

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    std::pair<int,int> valPair;

    public:
        std::pair<const int,int> & getPairByReference();
};

std::pair<const int,int> & A::getPairByReference()
{
    return valPair;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.getPairByReference();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting below error while compiling it:

```
try-5.cpp: In member function ‘std::pair<const int, int>& A::getPairByReference()’:
try-5.cpp:15:12: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::pair<const int, int>&’ from expression of type ‘std::pair<int, int>’
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong with the question?

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of context. What is curr, what is the reference that the error message mentions, etc. Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @Eichhörnchen - I mentioned in questions thatcurr->valPair is std::pair<string,int>

Comment: If you convert an X to a Y, you have made a new Y. What are you trying to do and what do you not want to do?

Comment: Sorry, if the question is confusing.. I will add a small test code.

Comment: It seems like you are asking how to convert a `std::pair<string, int>` to a `std::pair<const string, int>` without copying the string, is that correct?

Comment: @Eichhörnchen - Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is only possible if `curr->valPair` is not needed anymore after the conversion, then

```
std::pair<const string, int> newPair(std::move(curr->valPair));
```

moves the `std::pair<string, int>` through move construction into a `std::pair<const string, int>`.

If the value of `curr->valPair` must be retained there is no way of doing this because type conversion requires construction of an instance of the destination type. Copying the string can only be avoided through a move.

However you probably want to do this conversion because you need the specific destination type with `const string` somewhere. It would be better if you explained the intended usage. The problem likely lies there.

After question edit:

You cannot have a reference of type `std::pair<const int, int>&` pointing to an object of type `std::pair<int, int>`. These are two completely independent types. You need to construct an object of type `std::pair<const int, int>` first before you can have a reference to such a type.

Additional note:

`reinterpret_cast` may be valid here (and would result in exceptions to my statements above), I am not sure, [here is a discussion on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272141/is-casting-stdpairt1-t2-const-to-stdpairt1-const-t2-const-safe). See @StoryTeller's answer.

Comment: I have added a sample code and I am trying to do something similar. I want to return reference of valPair as in code in question.

Comment: @MayankJain Extended my answer, I think you are running into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: In this case I will change my member of class itself. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got what you want. You have a class member that is a `pair<T, U>` (non-const), but want the user of the class to reference that member, but also want to disallow the user to modify the first item. Am I right?

Instead of making reference to a pair with different const-qualifier for the template arguments (`pair<const T, U>&` from `pair<T, U>`) maybe you can use a pair of references with different const-qualifier (`pair<const T&, U&>` instead of `pair<const T, U>&`).

Constructing a pair of references is much cheaper than copying the members. And the copy probably wouldn't make sense if you do want the user to modify the second parameter on the original instance.

To construct the pair of references:

```
std::pair<const string&, int&> A::getPairByReference()
{
    return {valPair.first, valPair.second};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though a `std::string` is implicitly convertible to `const std::string`, the two pair types are distinct.
What you seek to do is a `reinterpret_cast` to `std::pair<const std::string, int>&`.

Doing a `reinterpret_cast` means you suppress almost all compiler diagnostics by going completely around the type system. In this case it may be fairly benign, but in general you better know exactly what you are doing.